# How to use a list to populate a grid?

Tags: java, list

I am trying to get this code to read in a text file and then populate a 15x15 grid with the numbers from the file. What it is doing is only populating the grid with 0's. I am not sure how to fix it, but I think the issue is with how I am trying to use list.indexOf() in the loop.

I have tried switching to use list.get(i) or using j, which has not worked the way I need it to.

```
public Grid(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //reading file using scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    //first number is the dimension for rows
    this.rows = sc.nextInt();
    //since it is square matrix second dimension is same as first
    this.cols = this.rows;
    grid = new boolean[rows][cols];

    String longNumber = sc.next();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(char ch : longNumber.toCharArray()) {
        list.add( Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ch)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            //reading from file 1 and 0 if 1 then store true else store false in grid
            if (list.indexOf(i) == 1)
                grid[i][j] = true;
            else
                grid[i][j] = false;
        }
}
```

I am getting an output showing a 15x15 block of 0's, instead of the 1's and 0's that are being read in from the text file. The text file should be read in and displayed (along with a count of blobs or clumps of 1's), but this is not happening. If you need the rest of the code, please let me know. I am required to read in a file, which contains an int (15) which is used to make the grid, and then 15 lines of 1's and 0's, which should be displayed in the same way when the program works properly.

Comment: Well what is the input string you entered for the grid?

Comment: its the name of the file (blob.txt)
The file looks like this
15
000001111010000
000000100010000
100000010010001
000000011100000
000000000000000
000011000000000
000000000000000
001111000001000
000110000001000
000000100001000
000001100001100
000000100001111
000001111111111
000010000001111
000100000001111

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting it into a `List<Integer>`? You can simply work with `String` that you got from the file.

For each row, you'll have to get a `String` and then for each of such a `String` you can do `charAt()` to check what is the character there and store `true` or `false` in `grid` accordingly.

The code will look something like this:

```java
this.rows = sc.nextInt();
//since it is square matrix second dimension is same as first
this.cols = this.rows;
grid = new boolean[rows][cols];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    String longNumber = sc.next();
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        //reading from file 1 and 0 if 1 then store true else store false in grid
        grid[i][j] = (longNumber.charAt(j) == 1);
    }
}
```

Notice that I've placed `String longNumber = sc.next()` in the outer loop.

HTH

Comment: I just tried this, and I still get all 0's in the output. I was doing that before because the input file was coming in with each row as an int, and causing exceptions. I was trying to break it up into individual digits to populate the grid

Comment: You can debug you code, and put breakpoints and check what's the value of `rows` and `longNumber` during each iteration, so that you can pin-point what's going wrong.